# sort input/checkbox elements alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large list of checkboxes (600+), would it be possible to use js to sort them alphabetically and then rearrange them by manipulating the dom?

from

```
 <form id="stuff">
      <input type="checkbox" value="bbb" /> bbb
      <input type="checkbox" value="aaa" /> aaa
      <input type="checkbox" value="ccc" /> ccc
 </form>
```

to

```
 <form id="stuff">
      <input type="checkbox" value="aaa" /> aaa
      <input type="checkbox" value="bbb" /> bbb
      <input type="checkbox" value="ccc" /> ccc
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you explain the question again. I will try help you

Comment: Get the values of each on using `.val()`, then identify which comes first using maybe a bubble sort(if you don't have too many items), then re-arrange in the DOM accordingly.

Comment: I rephrased my original question. there will be 600+ items, would it be efficient then to use a bubble sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you can wrap them in label, which is a good practice to do anyways, you can do this:

#### Html

```
<form id="stuff">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="bbb" />bbb</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="aaa" />aaa</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="ccc" />ccc</label>
</form>
```

#### Script

```
var sortByText = function (a, b) {
     return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var sorted = $('#stuff label').sort(sortByText);
     $('#stuff').append(sorted);

 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4pmvE/)**